# redirecting the URL from cloudfront to API Gateway based on path

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

I am trying to achieve redirection from cloudfront to API gateway based on the path.
I have my UI with a cloudfront distribution with source being S3 bucket hosted on for eg.

```
www.example.com
```

and it serves the requests.

I want the URLs with the pattern

```
www.example.com/share/*
```

to be redirected to API Gateway. The API Gateway has redirection internally where it points to other URLs.

If I use the API gateway endpoint directly in the browser, it fetches the expected result.

I am unsure of how to redirect from cloudfront to API Gateway. I have put cloudwatch logs on API Gateway and can see that cloudfront to API Gateway Redirection isn't working.

I have tried adding API Gateway as origin and add the same as a behaviour in cloudfront, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do redirect by using [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) in CloudFront. AWS provides an example redirect function [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect).

Example below

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
     */
    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://URL/PATH',
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

**However** it seems like perhaps rather than doing a redirect you should consider using a different a secondary origin in your CloudFront distribution to serve the API Gateway path if it is part of your application.

To do this you would need to add a [custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) to your API Gateway with the domain name of your site and then within CloudFront add an origin with a matching pattern of `/share` to forward to your API Gateway.

Take a read of [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/) for more information.

Comment: I went ahead with using API Gateway redirect by adding a custom domain and adding that custom domain to route 53 as well. Then added this subdomain as a origin in cloudfront and attached a behaviour alongside with it. We also needed to add the custom domain name to CNAMEs under that cloudfront distribution. Thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [lambda@edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) for a [viewer request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#example-viewer-request) to return `302` HTTP code to the client with redirection url.

- [Generating an HTTP Redirect (Generated Response)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect)

In python, such a lambda could look like (from docs):

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
     # logic to check the url and generate new url.
     
     response = {
         'status': '302',
         'statusDescription': 'Found',
         'headers': {
             'location': [{
                 'key': 'Location',
                 'value': '<your-api-gateway-url>'
             }]
         }
     }
     
     return response
```